# CANNOT POST Express/ connect-multiparty/postman

Tags: express

estoy tratando subir una imagen desde postman utilizando express/connectmultiparty y me genera el siguiente error.

[introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xi8gO.jpg)
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Soy nuevo y recién estoy aprendiendo, si me podrian dar una mano, desde ya muchas gracias.

Comment: El código debe ir como texto, por favor, solo usa imágenes cuando sea absolutamente necesario. ;)

Comment: Nunca he probado connect-multipart. Dale una prueba a Multer yo lo he uado en apps de producción sin falla. https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/multer.html